# In Typesense last fields in my query are sometimes completly ignored and are not being searched

Tags: reactjs, search, full-text-search, typesense

I have this case. I search for by 4 queries -

```
query_by=name,description,responses,request
```

I know that if no query_by_weights are not provided then fields earlier in the query_by list will be considered to have greater weight.
because of this sometimes the results that I have in my request field are completely ignored are search results
are not returned at all.

when I move a request, for example, after the name then everything is great. but now my descriptions are not being searched.
Is there a way to balance these behaviours?
I also tried to use query_by_weights nothing really changed.

```
query_by=name,description, responses,request&per_page=10&query_by_weights=1,1,1,1
```

this is how I have it right now.
I tried to add more weight to the request and response, but then again, my name and description queries were lost.

Thanks for the help :)

I expect to get the results when searching by request and does not matter where
my request is in my query_by.